Recover VDI btrfs data that got corrupted by mounting
I have a VDI file that I mounted a filesystem of:
sudo qemu-nbd -c /dev/nbd0 "file.vdi"

sudo mount /dev/nbd0p2 /mnt/path/

This succeeded, but I thought it was not the partition I needed, thus I unmounted it and attempted to mount another one.
It failed, as did the original partition/filesystem afterwards.
mount: /mnt/path: can't read superblock on /dev/nbd0p2.
dmesg(1) may have more information after failed mount system call.
Thinking that I have another copy of this VDI (and in my infinite wisdom) I also ran:
btrfs check --repair
btrfs rescue chunk-recover

Listing roots fails:
> sudo btrfs restore -l /dev/nbd0p2
checksum verify failed on 31375360 wanted 0xb3b570ff found 0x7c2da2ef
checksum verify failed on 31375360 wanted 0xb3b570ff found 0xd6010b64
checksum verify failed on 31375360 wanted 0xb3b570ff found 0x7c2da2ef
Csum didn't match
Couldn't read tree root
Could not open root, trying backup super
checksum verify failed on 30638080 wanted 0x00000000 found 0x5c985a6d
checksum verify failed on 30638080 wanted 0x00000000 found 0xa2464f60
checksum verify failed on 30638080 wanted 0x00000000 found 0x5c985a6d
bad tree block 30638080, bytenr mismatch, want=30638080, have=0
Could not open root, trying backup super
ERROR: superblock bytenr 274877906944 is larger than device size 32201768960
Could not open root, trying backup super

Later it turned out that I do not, in fact, have another copy of the VDI file.
Is there any reasonable way I could restore files from this VDI file?
dmesg has:
[Thu Nov 28 13:39:51 2024] [  T17842] BTRFS: device fsid 28620cea-a4ac-452b-9cbc-746eb3195059 devid 1 transid 532124 /dev/nbd0p2 (43:2) scanned by mount (17842)
[Thu Nov 28 13:39:51 2024] [  T17842] BTRFS info (device nbd0p2): first mount of filesystem 28620cea-a4ac-452b-9cbc-746eb3195059
[Thu Nov 28 13:39:51 2024] [  T17842] BTRFS info (device nbd0p2): using crc32c (crc32c-generic) checksum algorithm
[Thu Nov 28 13:39:51 2024] [  T17842] BTRFS info (device nbd0p2): using free-space-tree
[Thu Nov 28 13:39:51 2024] [  T17809] BTRFS warning (device nbd0p2): checksum verify failed on logical 31375360 mirror 1 wanted 0xb3b570ff found 0x7c2da2ef level 0
[Thu Nov 28 13:39:51 2024] [  T17809] BTRFS warning (device nbd0p2): checksum verify failed on logical 31375360 mirror 2 wanted 0xb3b570ff found 0xd6010b64 level 0
[Thu Nov 28 13:39:51 2024] [  T17842] BTRFS warning (device nbd0p2): couldn't read tree root
[Thu Nov 28 13:39:51 2024] [  T17842] BTRFS error (device nbd0p2): open_ctree failed

The VDI file can still be detached:
sudo qemu-nbd -d /dev/nbd0
/dev/nbd0 disconnected
And attached successfully.
